# Can webassembly push output to javascript?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, web, webassembly

Say I have a program that is running in webassembly in my browser and I want to take input that the user puts in that program and have it output to other parts of my program. For example, say I want to make a really graphically fancy input box  in unity (not that this would ever be practical but just as an example) - can unity take this input that I type in the input box and then output it through webassembly? I could see this as being very cool for custom components, but all the webassembly demos I've seen only take data in to the compiled program (a la flash player or similar).

Thanks!

Comment: JS and Webassembly share the same memory. So yes they can definetly communicate

Answer (score 0):

Pushing data from webassebly to javascript i possible you just need to call from webassembly javascript function that will handle that data [how to do it in C](https://medium.com/@c.gerard.gallant/webassembly-calling-into-javascript-from-bare-bones-c-code-7d8ab5e331a) for more information.

For Unity you should stick to official method of calling javascript function from unity scripts [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)